# How to make a deep copy, when shared pointers are involved?

Tags: c++, qt, copy, copy-constructor

I am having a structure of three classes A, B and C, which can have ownership of each other. There can be two objects having ownership of the same object. There can not be a circular dependency. You can think of the structure as an acyclic graph with A being the unique root.
I want to make a copy of the whole structure and it needs to be a deep copy. I am using the copy-swap idiom and it works like a charm, except when facing multiple ownership:

```
shared_ptr<A> a { new A {} };
shared_ptr<B> b { new B {} };
shared_ptr<C> c { new C {} };
//Add only stores a copy of the shared pointer
a.add(b);
a.add(c);
b.add(c);
//This will produce two copies of c
shared_ptr<A> newA { new A {a} };
```

The last line will actually make two independent copies of `c`, one in the copy constructor of `a` and one in the copy constructor of `b`.

How do I solve this problem?

My ideas:

1. Instantiate all of the objects and iterate over the full structure in the copy-constructor of A and redirect the smart pointers of duplicate objects to the same one (inefficient).
2. Use some kind of factory that decides whether a new object is created (the elements in my structure have a unique ID, so that would be easy), or a smart_ptr to an existing one is passed. (I don't know how to tell the factory when to clear it's contents, so the factory no longer owns the objects and multiple copies can be made)

Comment: None of qt specifics or purely C++ 11 question. And I would define the deep copy more detailed whether it involves cloning of objects or not. To simplify I would recreate all the objects and pointers as well. And to track circular dependencies some std::set<void*> setCollection can be used so that you memorizing all the pointers traversed there regardless of their type and when you hit one again than you should stop traversing.